# IBM Bluemix Message Hub - Message Connect's Stream is not running

Tags: ibm-cloud, message, message-hub

When I tried to create the Message Stream (Source: MQ Light) in Message Connect, the stream is not going to running state instead to error.

The steps I followed:

1. Created Message Hub: Its working fine as I connected to this using APache Kafka API
2. Created Secure Gateway to my Local MQ: Its also working fine as I am able to publish to my Local MQ through Secure Gateway
3. Created Message Connect
4. Created Message Stream:
   i. Given Name
   ii. Selected MQ Light as my Source of events
   iii. Selected Secure Gateway
   iv. And the corresponding Destination
   v. Tried to create Stream, but the result is "Status: Error"

[Bluemix Message Connect Service Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBU6N.png)

I dont know where to see the logs as I am new to Bluemix. So please let me know what steps I missed or how to debug this?

Also when I tried to create the Twitter Message Stream also its behaving same. Means not running at all, going into error status without showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you viewed this video which helps walk you through the steps?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3PbU69yKiY

Also, confirm that the info you entered for your configuration is valid  [image]

[image]

Comment: Was your MQ Light Secure Gateway connection showing as enabled and running before you added the stream? See example in pic above ^^